# How to know if a point intersects a 3D object in a SolidWorks generated CAD file?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, cad, solidworks

For any SolidWorks generated CAD file, such as Part, IGES, STEP, ACIS, etc., is there a relatively simple way to know if a 3D point intersects a complex 3D shape? I do not need to display the object in my application.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

P.S.
My question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786382/how-to-know-if-a-point-is-inside-a-complex-3d-shape-ply-file), but I am not using Java nor PLY file.

Comment: In a stl file (for example), you can iterate through all faces and do some triangulation.
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EqnsOfPlanes.aspx . 
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful comment. You said "for example", so is there any other format I can work with? Do you believe that STL is the simplest format one may utilize?

Comment: I don't know others formats, but .stl can be in clear text file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29 . Processing time will take a lot of time

Comment: Oh, I see. I wrote a simple code that loads an STL file. As you said, the format is quite clear but it can be pretty time consuming to determine whether a point is inside the shape or not, especially that the process should be repeated for a large number of points.

Comment: Have you checked the SolidWorks API? By intersect, do you mean the point is located on edge, surface, vertex or the 3D point or inside the 3D shape?

Comment: No, I haven't because I needed to do it in my application. Yes, by intersect I meant almost all the situations you've mentioned. I already wrote a code which loads an STL file and detects if any arbitrary point is located on an edge or face, or if it's placed inside/outside the shape.

Comment: actually your application will use the solidworks interop assemblies to figure that out and return the result to your application, so technically speaking you're doing inside application

Comment: Well, could you please post a code snippet showing how one may utilize those assemblies? I am mostly using C#, however, any other programming language would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to [connect to solidworks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoXJGKAwhbc) instance and use [RayIntersections method](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IModelDoc2~RayIntersections.html) from their API. Shoot your ray in any direction, if number of intersections is odd - your point is located within the body.

Comment: i tired to use it, that api is making a crash can you please give samle code like how to use it

Comment: That'll take considerably more time than I'm willing to commit. But if you share your code and tell me where and how it crashes I may be able to help.

Comment: up to you. Create a new SO question and paste a link here. OR 
add code to pastebin/github and paste link here. Don't forget to mention what exception you're getting and on what line.